# Basis for believing services are for the regenerate?

Tags: biblical-basis, protestantism, reformed-theology, worship, sabbath

This is actually needed for an upcoming communication.

I’ve heard several Reformed Theology preachers criticizing the focus some modern Protestant churches have on using services largely or even primarily for evangelizing. **They said the physical church, especially Sunday services, should ideally be for leaders to uplift the Body and for having community between saved, regenerate sinners**.

I haven’t yet come across this in the Bible (I’m fairly new so that doesn’t imply much).  **Is the basis for this the Bible, or church fathers, etc?** Thank you .

---

There are no prior questions that *I* found relevant enough to link.

If and only if a distinction within Protestantism is necessary, you can focus on Reformed Theology. This is not about whether we must go to church etc, but where the church is generally advised to put our focus. Bible verses would be especially helpful.

Comment: Some texts make a difference between public preaching and private gathering : _And of the rest durst no man join himself to them: but the people magnified them. And believers were the more added to the Lord, multitudes both of men and women._ Acts 5:14. Up-voted +1.

Comment: @NigelJ hope to get an answer to this one most of all. Ive never done a bounty guess i need to wait though